# Tailwind & PostCSS error when adding Svelte to an Astro project

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, astrojs

I have been using Astro with Tailwind for a project, however upon adding Svelte to the project with a simple `npx astro add svelte`, a simple `npm run dev` produces this error:

```
error   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postcss')
  File:
    C:\Users\**\node_modules\@astrojs\tailwind\dist\index.js:78:22
  Code:
    77 |         const tailwindConfig = (userConfig == null ? void 0 : userConfig.value) ?? getDefaultTailwindConfig(config.srcDir);
    > 78 |         config.style.postcss.plugins.push(tailwindPlugin(tailwindConfig));
         |                      ^
      79 |         config.style.postcss.plugins.push(autoprefixerPlugin);
      80 |         if (applyBaseStyles) {
      81 |           injectScript("page-ssr", `import '@astrojs/tailwind/base.css';`);
  Stacktrace:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postcss')
    at astro:config:setup (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/@astrojs/tailwind/dist/index.js:78:22)
    at async withTakingALongTimeMsg (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/integrations/index.js:18:18)
    at async runHookConfigSetup (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/integrations/index.js:95:7)
    at async createContainer (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/core/dev/container.js:30:14)
    at async createContainerWithAutomaticRestart (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/core/dev/restart.js:90:28)
    at async dev (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/core/dev/dev.js:32:19)
    at async runCommand (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:155:7)
    at async cli (file:///C:/Users/**/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:213:5)
```

I have tried a few workarounds like creating a `postcss.config.js` file, however it hasn't yielded any results.

Would appreciate any insights on what may be causing this issue and any suggestions for fixing it.

Comment: Show us the content of tailwind.config.cjs

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The issue is solved and I'll post a answer here shortly. In short, this was due to an issue with the versions of the packages being used. Nevertheless, thanks for responding to the question and indirectly reminding me to to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was either due to an issue with `Astro v2.5.5` or `astrojs/tailwind v2.1.3` (most likely the latter).

I added the Svelte integration to an existing project (`npx astro add svelte`) that was using `Astro v1.9.0` with `astrojs/tailwind v2.1.3`. The latest version of the Svelte integration required a newer version of Astro, so it automatically upgraded the project to `Astro v2.5.5` which was only released 15 hours ago at the time.

Few hours later, I noticed that `v2.6.6` was out. I upgraded to that version and uninstalled `tailwind` and `svelte`. Thereafter, I re-ran `npx astro add svelte` & `npx astro add tailwind` to make sure that I am using the latest versions of the two integrations. This bumped up my tailwind integration to `astrojs/tailwind v4.0.0`.

That solved the issue.

While researching this error earlier, I had come across a few closed issues (opened only a few months ago) on the Astro repo discussing similar errors while trying to use Svelte and Tailwind together with Astro. The workarounds suggested there didn't seem to work for me, but there was a discussion around introducing a patch in one of the integrations. Thus, I am assuming that these issues were patched in newer releases of (mostly likely) the `astrojs/tailwind` integration (it wasn't immediately clear from the multiple issue threads where this was patched).

Putting this out there for anyone that may face something similar in the future.